# Why is this do-while loop not working appropriately?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I had this assignment for school, and I had the idea to further it by incorporating a do loop, but it isn't working the way it was meant to. I was trying to make it repeat the entire program until the input was correct, say if someone entered a string rather an integer then it would repeat the program.

How would I do this?

Please don't offer better ways of writing this program as it is what the instructor is looking for. I know there are better ways of writing it as I have already done so.

```
public class Grade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader(System.in);

        int i = 1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your grade percentage:");
            int percent = (int) console.readDouble();
            Math.round(percent);
            percent = (int) percent / 10;
            String grade ="Input was not valid";

            if(percent <= 5){
                grade = "Your grade is an F, Work Harder so you won't have to retake!";
                System.out.println(grade);
                i = 9999999;
            }else{
                switch (percent){

                case 6:
                    grade = "Your grade is a D, work harder";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i = 9999999;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    grade = "Your grade is a C, That's average but you could do better.";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i = 9999999;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    grade = "Your grade is a B, That is pretty good but strive for that A";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i = 9999999;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    grade = "Your grade is a A, Good Work!!";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i = 9999999;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    grade = "Your grade is a A, Good Work!!";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i = 9999999;
                    break;
                default:
                    grade = "Your input was invalid, Please enter your grade percentage.";
                    System.out.println(grade);
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(i != 9999999);
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer division warning! Warning! Pass by value warning! Those are two things you should look into.

Comment: If user enter incorrect data then it will throw the exception and you are not catching it at all

Comment: What exactly is the expected behaviour? BTW why do you want to round an int?

Comment: yes it should throw exception if you enter string rather than integer

Comment: try to debug it by for example outputting also the i value via System.out.println or alternatively setting some breakpoints

Comment: Would someone care to explain what you mean^^^^

Comment: You can improve the way you have written the program (I am not talking about the logic but the use of variables). Also, Theodore's answer will help perform what you want. Just saying.

Comment: Actually my answer was crap; hence I deleted it.  @raphw nails it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a topic called `Exception handling` that you should look into

to illustrate with an example

```
boolean done = false;
do {

 try{
  System.out.println("Enter your percentage");
  int percent = (int) console.readDouble();

  // more code
  // if the condition is satisfied then assign done = true;

 } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please input only numbers");
 }
} while(!done);
```

if something other than a number is entered by the user then `readDouble` method would throw an exception, an `InputMismatchException` in this case.

The control will go to the `catch` block and the warning message would be printed to the user without executing any of the other code that follows the `readDouble` method.

And since the `boolean` value of the variable `done` would still be false, the while loop will be executed again.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, except it took me time figuring out that it was a NumberFormatException rather an InputMismatchException
ThankYou!

Comment: since i didn't know what this `ConsoleReader` class is i used the `Console` class in my example.. glad i could be of help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is not doing what you expect it does:

```
int percent = (int) console.readDouble();
Math.round(percent);
percent = (int) percent / 10;
```

The `Math#round` function is returning a rounded value, it will not round the one that is assigned to `percent`. Also, it would not have an effect since there is no such thing as a rounded `int`. You can only call the method because there is type widening applied by the Java compiler. There is a good chance that this is messing with your data. Simply casting a `double` to an `int` is not a good way of converting data.

Furthermore, the `console.readDouble()` will cause an exception to be thrown when a user entered something that cannot be parsed as a double. You should attempt to read the value within a `try catch` block where you handle invalid inputs in the `catch` block.